# MySQL pipe separated value vs mapping table

Tags: mysql

I've a case where 1 record there can be multiple rows possible of master table.

e.g.

```
sports master table
Cycling
Rafting
Shooting
Football
Cricket
```

Now I've person table

```
Person
id
first_name
last_name
```

Can I have sports id as foreign key in Person table as pipe separated field or can I create separate table which will act as mapping table

e.g.

```
sports_persons_mapping
id
person_id
sports_id
```

Come to the situation to select from 2 options.

Pipe separated field in person table or mapping table sports_persons_mapping?

In search which is effective or which is more effective and why?

Comment: ["associative entity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities)

Answer (score 4):

Use the mappting table as you call it. Avoid using columns with comma-separated or pipe-separated values as this goes against good database design practices and make your life impossible when you have to start looking for data, inserting new data, etc. Your queries become overly complicated, difficult to write and your query performance is guaranteed to be less than optimal.

Comment: Thanks lcarus, It is great help.